# Unroasted coffee beans in La Paz, Bolivia

Tags: shopping, bolivia, la-paz, food-and-drink

Is there a place in La Paz where I could buy beans straight from farms, before they are processed? I have a couple of friends who'd want to roast their beans up to their liking, so I'd like to buy them some beans as close to the source as possible. I don't have much time to travel, so places in La Paz are preferred. I've done some research, but to no avail.

Comment: In Mexico in the 1980s, many big Public Markets in the center of cities sold unroasted coffee beans and cocoa beans. They also roasted them to your desires. If no one answers, try looking at the markets and reporting back as to what you find.

Comment: Oh I checked almost every stand at Villa Fatima markets, also all the markets around San Francisco plaza... nada. They even laughed at me frequently.

Answer (score 2):

My best tip for La Paz would be to find a decent taxi driver and ask him to take you to some place where they have the beans. Offer him a bonus if he makes you happy.

Remember not to wrap the beans in plastic. They should be stored somewhere dry and cool. I forgot to take some beans I bought out of their plastic bag and ruined them.

Also remember that unroasted beans in some countries might be considered fresh agricultural product and as such can be forbidden to import to some countries..